# How to get attribute values from a composition in the form with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

in Spring we get the value of an input by its name, but if the attribute is of a composition of another class, how do we link this input to the attribute?

Comment: what do you mean by *composition of another class* ?? explain more.

Comment: ex:

public class User{ 
 String name;
 Address a = new Address();
}

public class Address{
 String street;
}

<input name="street"> *
this is only for the attribute of the class Address, but for the attribute of the class User?

Comment: probably I am getting you. But you need to describe more on your problem. Like show us a scenario and so far sample codes that depicts your concern.

Comment: Please update your question with these scenario and codes you provided in comments

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a form, then Use Spring Form tags to construct your form. Then Use Spring’s @RequestBody annotation to map the form attributes to your object like.

`RequestMapping(‘/form-submit’)
Public @RequestBody User getFormData () {
//spring automatically maps the form data to your object . Now u can access the User Object here
}`

Comment: `@RequestBody` is used for deserialization of object passed in Request parameter. That involves MessageConverters. Like its in the case for Json data that is placed in request. And moreover you put it in the wrong place. So your answer is **Misguiding**.

Answer (score 0):

In **Spring MVC** you can bind a *Model* (or a object as you say) in the *Request Handler* (or the Controller method that is mapped with that request) with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation like

```
@PostMapping("/show")
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
   // process your model
   return "viewName";
}
```

Here the `@ModelAttribute("user")` annotation hints Spring MVC to build a *User* object from the available *Request parameters* that is later get plugged in into as *user* variable.

### Binding Composite Model

Binding a composite model is nothing different than mentioned above. But in that case your *Request Parameters* should be in such way that the association is understandable to *Spring MVC*. Say if you have a `User` class having association of `Address` like

```
public class User {
   private String name;
   private Address address;
   //getter-setter
}

public class Address {
  private String house;
  private String street;
  //getter-setter
}
```

And you need to bind `User` as Model Attribute then your Request parameters should have parameters like

```
name: Luiz Felipe
address.house: 10/1
address.street: park avenue
```

Spring will automatically understand that composite association and will bind the `User` object properly.